# Symfony2, empty GET variables in production

Tags: php, symfony

I need to get the "name" GET var in this url:

```
www.mydomain.com/?n=me
```

This is how I get it:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$name = $request->query->get('n');
```

It works on my localhost server, but on the production server the $name var is empty. What could cause this?

**Edit:**

I looked at my code again and I saw that somewhere along the way the mysql_real_escape_string() function is used. Effectively, this is done:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$name = $request->query->get('n');
$safeName = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

Which result in $safeName being null and $name holding the correct value. So the real question would be why mysql_real_escape_string() is removing the value.

Comment: So the question is why are you calling this function? Are you using Doctrine to query your database? If yes, you don't need to sanitize `$name`. [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html)

Comment: I used this function because this is how I always did it before. Yes I'm using Doctrine.

Comment: What happens when you use `$name = $request->query->get('n', 'bob');` ? Is `$name` set to 'bob'?

Comment: @BigJ that's weird, it means that `n` is not set. Does `$request->query->has('n');` return true?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code instead:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$name = $request->query->get('n');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-object

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help